# Dynamic conditions query in RoR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make query in RoR, but my conditions are coming from **params** and changing dynamically.

I've tried this:

```
@userlist = User.find(:all, conditions:{(name:params[:name] if params[:name] != nil), (lastname:params[:lastname] if params[:lastname] != nil)})
```

It's just my imagination, but shows what I mean.

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Rails 3:

```
@userlist = User.scoped
@userlist = @userlist.where(name: params[:name]) if params[:name].present?
@userlist = @userlist.where(lastname: params[:lastname]) if params[:lastname].present?
```

etc..

Comment: unfortunately not works with only name or lastname. works only when both params are present. sorry

Comment: Updated my answer. Try that. I guess it could be the reason why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like:

```
BlahController < ActiveController::Base
  before_filter :find_params, :only => :index

  def index
    @user_list = User.where(@filtered_params).all
  end

  def find_params
    @filtered_params = params[:name].present? ? "'name = ?', #{params[:name]}" : "'last_name = ?', #{params[:last_name]}"
  end

end
```

So I assume you only have two conditions, a `params[:name]` or a `params[:last_name]`. If there are more, simply change the ternary to a `if elsif` statement.

Comment: looked great, I've tried. You absolutely right about that I'm trying to build a filter. but after first request it seems like params for the name was saved and even adding new params not changing result. sorry

Comment: forgot the curly braces around the params. my bad.